# C compiler cannot create executables on OpenSUSE

Tags: c, linux, gcc, opensuse

I've tried to compile xdebug from sources, but I become this output:

> ```
> fobo66@linux-3z16:~/xdebug-2.3.3> ./configure
> configure: loading site script /usr/share/site/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
> checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
> checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
> checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
> checking for cc... cc
> checking whether the C compiler works... no
> configure: error: in `/home/fobo66/xdebug-2.3.3':
> configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
> See `config.log' for more details
> ```

[There is my config.log.](http://pastebin.com/15Vg0923)

I've found possible error:

> `/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
>   i386 architecture of input file '/usr/lib/crt1.o' is incompatible with
>   i386:x86-64 output
>   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
>   i386 architecture of input file '/usr/lib/crti.o' is incompatible with
>   i386:x86-64 output
>   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
>   i386 architecture of input file '/usr/lib/crtn.o' is incompatible with
>   i386:x86-64 output
>   /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
>   dynamic STT_GNU_IFUNC symbol 'strcmp' with pointer equality in
>   '/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../lib64/libc.a(strcmp.o)'
>   can not be used when making an executable; recompile with -fPIE and
>   relink with -pie`

So, how to fix this when my compiler don't work?

Comment: Did you install the GCC compiler?

Comment: Of course! Both cc and gcc somewhy, it was shipped with Zypper pattern "C/C++ Development"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I've just reinstall `glibc-devel` with correct architecture.

How to do it:

1. Go to YaST
2. Choose "Software Management" tool
3. In a search field type `glibc`
4. Mark packages `glibc` and `glibc-devel` for update (click on the checkboxes)
5. Choose `glibc` package
6. Click on the "Versions" tab in the bottom
7. Choose the version with correct architecture, e.g. `2.19-16.15.1-x86_64`
8. Choose `glibc-devel` package and do 6 and 7 for it
9. Click "Accept"
10. Wait for the end of the installation
11. Close the window

After this compilation should work properly.

This is Windows-like method, and this is a reason why it sucks:)

When somebody know how to do it from terminal, write answer here.

Answer (score 1):

try to compile some simple code with gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main () { printf("hello world\n"); return 0; }
```

with command

```
gcc -o simple simple.c
```

if there will be error like that "command not found", then then gcc is not located in the environment's path.

also make sure that gcc can find standard header files (like stdio.h and e.t.c)

Comment: Strange. There is an gcc's output: `gcc -o simple simple.c
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:402:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:27,
                 from simple.c:1:
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:10:27: fatal error: gnu/stubs-64.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
 # include <gnu/stubs-64.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.`

Comment: ah, try to install glibc-devel :)

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/bin/ld:
  i386 architecture of input file '/usr/lib/crt1.o' is incompatible with
  i386:x86-64 output`
It seems linker is getting 32-bit version of the required obj files where it needs 64-bit of them. Try with setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to appropriate paths from /usr/lib64, and recompile.

Comment: There is no needed 64-bit `crt1.o` etc. files in `/usr/lib64` somewhy. Maybe, I search in wrong location?

Comment: Is there no file named `crt1.o` in `/usr/lib*`? If not, then your system probably is missing `glibc-devel` packages. You can check if they are actually installed using command `rpm -qa | grep glibc`. If not installed, try installing `glibc-devel` packages.

Comment: It is already installed, but for i686 architecture. How can I reinstall it for x86-64?